# How to send to email (outlook) the selected items in SQL Server database using vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have 2 tables in my form, `RegisteredSchedule` and `TodaySchedule`. When the user inputs data such as Name, Gender, SchedueleDate and Incharge to my form and clicks the "Save" button, the data will go to the `RegisteredSchedule` table, and if the `ScheduleDate` set by users is equal to date `Now`, that record will show in `TodaySchedule` table and I want that selected data from SQL Server to be sent in an email - is that possible? Please help me I am a newbie.

Here is my code to if the ScheduleDate set by user is = DateNow . I want this select statement to be send in email also, not just show in table2.

```
Public Sub OnSchedule()
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("SERVER=x\x;database = 
 x; user=x;pwd=x; ")

    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand
    cmd.CommandText = String.Format("select PatientName,Gender,ScheduleDate,PersonInCharge from " _
    & "Schedule where ScheduleDate = CONVERT(date,getdate()) order by ScheduleDate")
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If dr.HasRows Then
        Dim dtSerial As New DataTable
        dtSerial.Load(dr)
        dgvOnSchedule.DataSource = dtSerial
    Else
        MsgBox("no data")

    End If
    dr.Close()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

here is my code in my email, i tried to put my select query in oMail.TextBody but didn't work. please suggest.

```
    Public Sub sendEmail()
    Dim oMail As New SmtpMail("TryIt")
    Dim oSmtp As New SmtpClient()
    oMail.To = New AddressCollection("x@x.co.th")
   oMail.Cc = New 
   AddressCollection("x@x.co.th,x@x.co.th")
   oMail.Subject = "test email from VB.NET project"

   'code below not work, what should i do to my oMail.textbody to show the 
   select condition ?

   oMail.TextBody = "On SChedule Date" & OnSchedule()



 Dim oServer As New SmtpServer("x.x.x.th")
   Try
        oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail)
        MessageBox.Show("success")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("no success")
    End Try     
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating the table as HTML object, you can use following code

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder("<table>")
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    sb.Append("<tr>")
    For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
        sb.Append("<td>")
        sb.Append(cell.Value)
        sb.Append("</td>")
    Next
    sb.Append("</tr>")
Next
sb.Append("</table>")
```

This will create an HTML table script similar to following sample

```
<table><tr><td>1</td><td>Pre-School A</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Pre-School B</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: it doesn't display in tabular format, how can i set my mail to support html ?  my result is same as your sample. i want it to display like a table. is it possible sir ?

Comment: 'oMail.TextBody = "" & sb.ToString()' i will not change that code ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that... In your code you used TextBody property of SMTPMail object, you should use HtmlBody property. So your code should be: oMail.HTMLBody = "" & sb.ToString()

Comment: Ok thanks, but still the records sent to email doesn't have table, i want all the data is inside the table. and can i add header to it ? i want it to looks like the table in sql server is it possible sir?

Comment: maybe your email client does not support html emails and converting to text, you might check your mail client tool as well

Comment: please vote my question to help me increase my reputation thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On your TextBody assignment, you have called method OnSchedule() which does not return anything back, only assigns and populates a datagridview object

You can use a StringBuilder object

Then read DataGridView data using foreach loops and append those values to the stringbuilder object

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            sb.Append(cell.Value);
            sb.Append("\t");
        }
        sb.AppendLine();
    }
    textBox1.Text= sb.ToString();
```

As the final step, use this stringbuilder value in your assignment as follows

```
oMail.TextBody = "On SChedule Date" & sb.ToString()
```

For VB.NET code equivalent of above C# code, please use following

```
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            sb.Append(cell.Value)
            sb.Append("\t")
        Next
    Next
```

Again you will use

```
oMail.TextBody = "On SChedule Date" & sb.ToString()
```

Comment: Sorry I am new here, where should i insert your code ? StringBuilder ? thanks for the answer. by the way i am using vb.net .

Comment: just above the "oMail.TextBody = "On SChedule Date" & OnSchedule()" and replace this code line with  "oMail.TextBody = "On SChedule Date" & sb.ToString()".... Please note that my code is in C#, you need to convert it to VB.NET ... You can use code converters http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: I tried to Convert your code to vb using the converter but it shows an error. CONVERSION ERROR: Code could not be converted. Details: what is the textbox1.text ? ?

Comment: just remove it, you don't need "textBox1.Text= sb.ToString();" just use sb.ToString() for your data to represent it as string. TEXTBOX1 was a control on WinForms application that I used for test

Comment: I'm trying to convert your code in vb but i can't can please help edit your code to vb ? thanks.

Comment: I added to codes, please mark as answer if it works for you

Comment: Yeah it works, thanks. but is it possible to put it on a table also ? so that it is easy to read when send in email ? and can i put a header ?

Comment: You can create an HTML table object. Before looping open a table tag <table> then while looping for cells use <td> and </td>'s after the loop close table with </table>. Of course if your email supports HTML then it will display in tabular format

Comment: please answer my question in this link, [Send to Email(Outlook) in a table format with Header.vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49488468/send-to-emailoutlook-in-a-table-format-with-header-vb-net) thanks in advance.