# Send to Email(Outlook) in a table format with Header.vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

This is a continuation from my previous question [How to send to email (outlook) the selected items in SQL Server database using vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49485648/how-to-send-to-email-outlook-the-selected-items-in-sql-server-database-using-v/49486234?noredirect=1#comment85976835_49486234)

Now I can send it but the format is not easy to understand so I want to send data to email in table format with header, So that it is easy to understand.

Here is what i have now:

```
'load the equipment on schedule on the 2nd table
Public Sub OnSchedule()
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("SERVER=L4SMTDB01\SMTDBS02;database = SMT_IT; user=sa;pwd=qwerty; ")

    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand
    cmd.CommandText = String.Format("select PatientName,Gender,ScheduleDate,PersonInCharge from " _
    & "Schedule where ScheduleDate = CONVERT(date,getdate()) order by ScheduleDate")
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If dr.HasRows Then
        Dim dtSerial As New DataTable
        dtSerial.Load(dr)
        dgvOnSchedule.DataSource = dtSerial
    Else
        MsgBox("no data")

    End If
    dr.Close()
    conn.Close()
End Sub


'send email

Public Sub sendEmail()
    Dim oMail As New SmtpMail("TryIt")
    Dim oSmtp As New SmtpClient()
    oMail.To = New AddressCollection("emil@calcomp.co.th")
   oMail.Cc = New AddressCollection("emil@calcomp.co.th,chokchai@calcomp.co.th")
    oMail.Subject = "Patient Schedule today"

    'send to email not in the table.
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvOnSchedule.Rows
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            sb.Append(cell.Value)
            sb.Append("||")
        Next
    Next
    oMail.TextBody = "" & sb.ToString()
    Dim oServer As New SmtpServer("mailpe.calcomp.co.th")
    Try
        oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail)
        MessageBox.Show("send to email success")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("no success")
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I edit my code in Email Methods as below:
I put the value of sb inside the table.

```
'send email method
Public Sub sendEmail()
    Dim oMail As New SmtpMail("TryIt")
    Dim oSmtp As New SmtpClient()
    oMail.HtmlBody = True
    oMail.To = New AddressCollection("emil@calcomp.co.th")
    oMail.Cc = New AddressCollection("emil@calcomp.co.th,chokchai@calcomp.co.th")
    oMail.Subject = "FIXTURE ON SCHEDULE"

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder("<table width='1000px' align='center' border='1' cellpadding='20' cellspacing='0' style='border'top:5px solid white;> " & _
                              "  <tr><th>PatientName</th> <th>Gender</th> <th>ScheduleDate</th> <th>PersonIncharge")
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvOnSchedule.Rows

        sb.Append("<tr>")
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            sb.Append("<td>")
            sb.Append(cell.Value)
            sb.Append("</td>")
        Next
        sb.Append("</tr>")
    Next
    sb.Append("</table>")
    oMail.HtmlBody = sb.ToString()
    Dim oServer As New SmtpServer("mailpe.calcomp.co.th")
    Try
        oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail)
        MessageBox.Show("send to email success")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("no success")
    End Try
End Sub
```